# Reproduce java.io.IOException: Data error (CRC)

Tags: java, crc

We have an application using update4j and got a bug report from a Windows user with the following stacktrace:

```
INFO [main]   (OurMain.java:70) - Fatal error details: A problem occurred during the update
com.example.updater.RuntimeFatalError: A problem occured during the update
    at com.example.updater.Updater.update(Updater.java:72)
    ...
Caused by: com.example.updater.RuntimeFatalError: A problem occurred during the update
    at com.example.updater.UpdateHandler.failed(UpdateHandler.java:78)
    at org.update4j.Configuration.updateImpl(Configuration.java:1048)
    at org.update4j.Configuration.update(Configuration.java:861)
    at org.update4j.Configuration.update(Configuration.java:845)
    at com.example.updater.Updater.update(Updater.java:70)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Adathiba (CRC)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read(FileDispatcherImpl.java:54)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at org.update4j.util.FileUtils.getChecksum(FileUtils.java:57)
    at org.update4j.FileMetadata.requiresUpdate(FileMetadata.java:371)
    at org.update4j.Configuration.updateImpl(Configuration.java:934)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

(I guess the "Adathiba (CRC)" message would be "Data error (CRC)" with an English locale.)

If I'm right update4j is trying to read a jar file from the disk here.

The user deleted our app and completely reinstalled it (which solved the problem) but it would be great to reproduce the bug an actually fix it since we got a few another similar bug reports (unfortunately with even less detail).

I have tried to create a broken input zip/jar file but update4j detected that its checksum is not the same as the checksum in its XML file and downloaded and replaced the file (as expected).

Any reference to the related OpenJDK (13, 14) source is welcome. I have checked `FileDispatcherImpl.java` and `FileDispatcherImpl.c` but I have found nothing related to CRC checks or errors.

So, here are my questions:

- In which case could the JVM throw this kind of `IOException`?
- Does it indicate a corrupted ZIP/JAR file? If yes, how can create a file which causes a similar exception (for testing)?
- Does it indicate a faulty hard disk (and the error came from the OS)?

Comment: This exception thrown from native method. It means that it's OS error. Most likely it indicates faulty hard disk. You can try to hack Jimfs to simulate that error.

Answer (score 0):

As @vbezhenar mentioned in his comment, it seems a native OS error message. I'm not familiar with JDK code, so take my (partial) answer with caution.

The `FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)` (from the stacktrace) is a native method:

```
static native int read0(FileDescriptor fd, long address, int len)
    throws IOException;
```

It's implemented in the [`FileDispatcherImpl.c` source file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/windows/native/libnio/ch/FileDispatcherImpl.c#l42) where if I'm right the

```
return convertReturnVal(env, (jint)read, JNI_TRUE);
```

statement throws the exception above.

[`convertReturnVal()` is implemented in the `IOUtil.c` file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/windows/native/libnio/ch/IOUtil.c#l81). It calls another method:

```
JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "Read/write failed");
```

It's implemented in `jni_util.c` file and the second parameter is named as `defaultDetail`. It calls
`JNU_ThrowByNameWithLastError()` which only parses the result of `ReadFile()` (called from `read0()`). Since value of `defaultDetail` (`Read/write failed`) is not shown in the stacktrace of the question I suppose the message comes from OS.